# Tapestry loop through nested map in tml file

Tags: java, list, loops, dictionary, tapestry

I have following map

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>>
```

This map is accessible through following method in java file.

```
public List<Entry<String, List<Entry<String, Long>>>> getByEventTypeSorted() {
    List<Entry<String, List<Entry<String, Long>>>> ret = new ArrayList<Entry<String, List<Entry<String, Long>>>>();
    ret.addAll((Collection<? extends Entry<String, List<Entry<String, Long>>>>) byEventType.entrySet());
    return ret;
}
```

Thus I am converting  `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` into `List<Entry<String, List<Entry<String, Long>>>>` and returning it.

Now, in my tml file I am trying to loop through it like this.

```
<tr t:type="Loop" t:source="summarizer.byEventTypeSorted" t:value="entry">
    <td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px">${entry.key}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px" t:type="Loop" t:source="${entry.value}" t:value="entry2"> 
        ${entry2.key}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Corresponding java file has following properties.

```
@Property
private Entry<String,Long> entry;
@Property
private Entry<String,Long> entry2;
```

When I run the above code. Following exception is generated.

```
Failure writing parameter 'value' of component ConceptSummaries:loop_1: Could not find a coercion from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Map$Entry.
```

If I change the type of property entry2 to String in java file like below.....

```
@Property
private Entry<String,Long> entry;
@Property
private String entry2;
```

And loop in tml file like below.

```
<tr t:type="Loop" t:source="summarizer.byEventTypeSorted" t:value="entry">
    <td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px">${entry.key}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px" t:type="Loop" t:source="${entry.value}" t:value="entry2"> 
        ${entry2}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then I get the whole list rendered as a single string.

This means that tapestry is converting the `List<Entry<String, Long>>` into a String.
I do not want that to happen as I want to loop through the list and access individual entries.

How to loop through these nested maps? And is there any way to retain the type of inner list and prevent tapestry from converting it into a string?

**Update:**
I was able to solve this problem using Lance Java's suggestions. Following are the details.

code in tml file.

```
<tr t:type="Loop" t:source="summarizer.byEventTypeSorted.entrySet()" t:value="entry">
    <td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px">${entry.key}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px" t:type="Loop" t:source="KeySetForEntryValue" t:value="entry2"> 
        ${entry2.key}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a getter method for `"KeySetForEntryValue"` and `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` in corresponding java class.

```
public Set<Entry<String, Long>> getKeySetForEntryValue(){
    return entry.getValue().entrySet();
}

public Map<String, Map<String, Long>> getByEventTypeSorted() {
    return byEventType;
}
```

And following are the properties in the same java class.

```
@Property
private Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> entry;
@Property
private Entry<String, Long> entry2;
```

Comment: You don't need to convert to a `List` since loop can iterate `java.util.Collection`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is with `t:source="${entry.value}"`

Using `${...}` in a template attribute causes the value to be [coerced](http://tapestry.apache.org/typecoercer-service.html) to a string

Try `t:source="entry.value"` instead.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
@Property
private Map<String, Map<String, Long>> byEventType;

@Property
private Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> entry;

@Property
private Entry<String, Long> entry2;

<tr t:type="Loop" t:source="byEventType.entrySet()" t:value="entry">
<td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px">${entry.key}</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 3px" t:type="Loop" t:source="entry.value.entrySet()" t:value="entry2"> 
    ${entry2.key} = ${entry2.value}
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been trying to get my code work using your suggestions. When above code is run you get an exception.

'Could not convert 'entry.value.keySet()' into a component parameter binding: Exception generating conduit for expression 'entry.value.keySet()': No public method 'keySet()' in class java.lang.Object.'

I am reading up on type coercion now to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Perhaps tapestry's property expression parser can't keep up with the generics. In which case you can extract `entry.value.keySet()` into a `getter` and invoke that instead.

Comment: Yes, I returned entry.value.entrySet() from a getter method in java class since the problem was that entrySet() method was not accessible in inner loop in tml file. It works now. Thanks once again! I have updated my answer to accommodate changes that did the trick.